# Convert wchar_t to string?

Tags: c++, wchar-t

I have a `wchar_t` I'd like to convert to a `string`. The string should then be read using `stringstream`. I have looked converting it over here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(v=vs.80).aspx but none of them return anything useable with `stringstream`. I'm  not very experienced with coding so I'm probably missing something really simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The appropriate thing to do is to use `wstring` and `wstringstream` if you need to work with wide characters.

Comment: so you want string or stringstream?

Comment: @Space_Cow that should be the answer :P

Answer (score 5):

If you do **actually** need a `string` from a `wchar_t*` then you will first need to convert the `wchar_t*` to a `char*`. There are various methods to do this depending on what compiler you are using. The simplest way is to use `wcstombs()` but there are caveats with that. Here is a good discussion on the matter, with some solutions that might inspire you http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/87362.

**However** you can just use `wstring` directly with `wchar_t*` as @Space_C0wb0y has mentioned. *If that is what you are looking for please mark his answer as correct.*